# unable to modify Sites domain name

Tags: force.com-sites

I'm in our production instance and on the Sites main page, where I want to modify our force.com domain.

Right now, it is set to:

`http://free-12415f14c3a-124e539428a-12a1ad6480d.force.com`

The input to change the domain name is grayed out and I can't change it.  I've been able to change the domain in other orgs without a problem

Why is the text input grayed out for the domain?  Is there something I need to do to be able to edit that?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak to whether/how you were able to change the Sites domain in other orgs, but as the text on that page says, you can only set it once, and I have never seen an org where it could be modified.

You can submit a support request asking them to change it. Especially since yours seems to have been pre-set to some programmatically generated value.

You can add custom domains to point to your sites, but you can't change the base force.com sites domain yourself.

Comment: hmmm, perhaps it has already been set by another user, but if that is the case, why would you be able to select the checkbox to agree to the terms, which activates the "Register My Force.com Domain" button so you can then register that domain that is not editable?  Maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: Yeah, I've seen that in an org that was created from a template org that had Sites enabled. Which is consistent with that long random-ish string they used. You'll definitely have to contact support. I tried all kinds of tricks when I had this problem before.

Comment: It's in a kind of limbo-ish state with the domain set, but Sites not yet enabled. Pain in the tush, that one.